# how to turn off tcp timestamps?

Tags: networking, tcp, sysctl, kernel-parameters

I tried to turn off the tcp timestamp but it didn't work.
The step i performed are the following:

```
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0
$ sysctl -p
$ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps (=> to be sure that it has been set to 0)
$ hping3 www.google.com -S -c 1 -p 443 --tcp-timestamp
```

and i obtained:

```
TCP timestamp: tcpts=2513557362
```

I also tried to sniff the traffic through wireshark and i saw that every tcp packet contains the value in the timestamps field.

I'm using Linux Debian 4.9.13.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

hping3 don't care about 'sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps', that's why it have '--tcp-timestamp' option.
Try to use curl (for example), you should see difference.